# Why file pointer acts different from normal pointer in C language?

Tags: c, file, pointers, memory-address, file-pointer

Here's my C code:

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"string.h"
#include"limits.h"

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int Array[2]={100,150};
    int *pArray=Array;
    int *qArray=pArray;
    qArray++;

    printf("pArray address:%p\n",pArray);
    printf("qArray address:%p\n",qArray);

    if(pArray!=qArray){
        printf("pArray not equals to qArray\n\n");
    }

    FILE *fp1=NULL,
         *fp2=NULL,
         *fp3=NULL,
         *fp4=NULL,
         *fp5=NULL;

    fp1=fopen("test.bin","rb+");
    if(fp1==NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    fp2=fp1;
    fp3=fp1;
    fp4=fp1;
    fp5=fp1;

    fseek(fp2,100l,SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(fp3,200l,SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(fp4,300l,SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(fp5,400l,SEEK_CUR);

    printf("fp1 position:%lu\n",ftell(fp1));
    printf("fp2 position:%lu\n",ftell(fp2));
    printf("fp3 position:%lu\n",ftell(fp3));
    printf("fp4 position:%lu\n",ftell(fp4));
    printf("fp5 position:%lu\n",ftell(fp5));

    if(fp1==fp5){
        printf("fp1 equals to fp5.\n");
    }

    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
$ ./program 
pArray address:0x7ffe5e6780a0
qArray address:0x7ffe5e6780a4
pArray not equals to qArray

fp1 position:1000
fp2 position:1000
fp3 position:1000
fp4 position:1000
fp5 position:1000
fp1 equals to fp5.
```

I made a conclusion: Moving a normal pointer does not affect the pointer that share address with it, but moving a file pointer with `fseek` function, however, does affect.

Why file pointer acts different from normal pointer?

Comment: You're not comparing the same things though. First you're printing a couple of memory addresses, and then a bunch of file offsets (that you got from `ftell`).

Comment: The file pointer isn't pointing to a location in the file, but to its control structure. It doesn't change while the file is open, and you must not change it either, although you might like to set it to `NULL` *after* you close the file. Your `fp1` ... `fp5` all point to the same control structure, and access the same file. Just like if you pass the file pointer to a function, it will be working with a *copy* of the file pointer.

Comment: ... and the position given by `ftell()` is `1000` because that is the sum of the `fseek()` offset calls that you made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `FILE *` is not a pointer to a file; it is a pointer to a `FILE`. Per C 2018 7.21.1 2, a `FILE` is:

> … an object type capable of recording all the information needed to control a stream, including its file position indicator, a pointer to its associated buffer (if any), an *error indicator* that records whether a read/write error has occurred, and an *end-of-file indicator* that records whether the end of the file has been reached…

Thus `fp2=fp1;` makes `fp2` point to the same object that is used to control the file, so any changes made to the object pointed to by `fp1` appear in the object pointed to by `fp2` and vice-versa because they are the same object.

`qArray++` changes the pointer `qArray`. `fseek(fp2,100l,SEEK_CUR);` changes the object pointed to by `fp2` (and the stream it controls). Similarly, if you called some routine `ChangeAnElementInArray(qArray, index, value)`, that would change an element in the array; it would not change the `qArray` pointer.

Also, a `FILE *` is not a position in a file. It is just a pointer to the data structure that is used to control the stream.

Comment: Thanks, I have a better understanding of FILE pointer now.